# Como pego a posição de uma marcador de uma mapa e adc num campo de texto automaticamente cada vez que eu posicione esse marcador?

Tags: javascript, html

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
function onMapClick(e) {
        popup
            .setLatLng(e.latlng)
            .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
            .openOn(macarte);
        var marker= L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(macarte)
        
    }
```

```html
 <title>Cadastro </title>
 

    <h2>Cadastre as Coordenadas </h2> 

   <table>
  <h3> <label for="Endereco">Endereço:</label> </h3>
  <input id="endereço"/>

  <h3> <label for="latitude">Latitude:</label> </h3>
    <input id="lat"/>
    
   <h3> <label for="longitude">Longitude:</label> </h3>
    <input id="lon"/>
<br> </br>
    <button> Salvar </button>
```

Comment: de que mapa você está falando? Aproveite e ajuste os seus `for=""`

Comment: openstreetmap com a biblioteca leaflet

Comment: e você não consegue adicioná-lo à pergunta?

Comment: vou tentar perai

Comment: só  consegui por a imagem mesmo

Comment: assim que eu clico em qualquer lugar do mapa, ele mostra no marcador a longitude e latitude e é essa informação que eu quero por naqueles dois ultimos campos de forma automatica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note que o valor de `e.latlng.toString()` retorna uma string no padrão:

```
LatLng(n1, n2)
```

Onde `n1` e `n2` são números que podem ser negativos e terem casas decimais separadas por ponto.

Neste caso, você pode usar uma expressão regular para retornar apenas `n1` e `n2`. A expressão seria:

```
/[\d|\.|-]+/g
```

Irá buscar apenas números (`\d`), ponto (`\.`) ou o sinal de negativo (hífen `-`). O sinal de mais `+` no final serve para unir 1 ou mais ocorrências. O caractere `|` significa "ou". Veja que coloquei o que quero achar entre colchetes `[]`, que representa o conjunto do que quero achar, separados por `|`. Ou seja, quero achar números ou ponto ou hífen, o resto seja descartado. O `g` é uma flag para buscar todas as ocorrências na string, não apenas a primeira que encontrar.

Essa expressão regular, usando `.match()`, irá retornar uma array com os dois valores:

```
[n1, n2]
```

Então basta pegar o índice `0` (`n1`) e jogar no input da latitude e o índice `1` (`n2`) no input da longitude.

Sua função ficará assim:

```
function onMapClick(e) {
   popup
   .setLatLng(e.latlng)
   .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
   .openOn(macarte);
   var marker= L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(macarte)

   var coords = e.latlng.toString().match(/[\d|\.|-]+/g);
   document.getElementById("lat").value = coords[0];
   document.getElementById("lon").value = coords[1];
}
```

Um exemplo de funcionamento:

```js
var string = "LatLng(-25.9898, -50.8877)";
var coords = string.match(/[\d|\.|-]+/g);
document.getElementById("lat").value = coords[0];
document.getElementById("lon").value = coords[1];
```

```html
Lat:<input id="lat"/>
<br>
Long: <input id="lon"/>
```

Comment: Muito obrigadaa, funcionou muito bem !!!!

Comment: Então pode marcar a resposta ;)